# Как загрузить трёхмерную модель или Heightmap из изображения в CSS 3

Tags: html5, css3, 3d

Люди, нужна помощь. Мне нужно загрузить ландшафт из чернобелой картинки, или формат 3ds, например, на н-страничку, но я не знаю как это сделать. Можно ли вообще загружать ландшафт или модель в CSS 3, и если да - то как?

Comment: Ваш вопрос неконкретен и требует указания подробностей, а возможно и вообще не относится к тематике программирования.

Comment: Уточните вопрос, нужно формироть svg или может просто карту с ланшафтом груть..
прикрепите картинку с примером